# Copy NSMutablearray to another

Tags: iphone, copy, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am trying to copy `NSMutableArray` to another but it does not show me anything at the `UITableView`:

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToAdd= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two"];

NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:objectsToAdd,nil];

NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.list addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
```

Nothing show up! What is wrong?

It crashes my app because I do not have nil at my `NSMutableArray` how can I add nil to it? `addobject:nil` does not work it crashes the app:

```
static NSString * DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier = 
@"DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: 
                         DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                   reuseIdentifier: DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier]
            autorelease];
}
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSString *rowString =nil;

rowString = [list objectAtIndex:row];


cell.textLabel.text = rowString;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
[rowString release];
return cell;
```

Comment: why something should be displayed? post your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method's code

Comment: Update how can i add nil to NSMutableArray with addObject? It crashes my app at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your initial call to alloc an NSMutableArray will most likely crash, since you don't have a nil terminator in your argument list.

Also, you have a local variable, list, and a property, list. Make sure you're instantiating what you think you are. You might need to do this:

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToAdd= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two", nil];

NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:objectsToAdd,nil];

self.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.list addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
```

Comment: NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objectsToAdd];

initWithObjects expects individual objects, not a mutable array. Also myArray is not mutable.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you:

```
NSMutableArray *result  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *result = [array mutableCopy]; //recommended
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems... One problem is that you're using 'initWithObjects' and adding the previous array.  This seems like unwanted behaviour since you most likely want to add the strings @"one" and @"two" to the array.  You most likely intended to use `initWithArray` or `addObjectsFromArray`.  (Doing it the way you did, will add the NSMutableArray (not its objects) to the list)

The second problem, when you use initWithObjects, you need to list each of the objects and then terminate the list with a nil value.  ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithObjects:))   In other words, you need to use...

```
NSMutableArray *objectsToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the local declaration of `list`in line 4 conflicts with the property.