# Putting objects from one NSMutableArray to another NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have 2 NSMutableArrays and i want to put certain object form 1 array to the other array I have already code written but it doesnt work and it gives me this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 296 beyond bounds [0 .. 295]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c9a012 0x10d7e7e 0x1c3c0b4 0x2f04 0xb20b90 0x1c59376 0x1c58e06 0x1c40a82 0x1c3ff44 0x1c3fe1b 0x1bf47e3 0x1bf4668 0x1f65c 0x252d 0x2455)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Initialisierung in viewdidload:

```
arrayLine1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:80000];
    arrayLine1a =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:70000];
    line1tagzahl=0;
    line1tagzahl2=0;
```

passing code:

```
for (int a=0; a<10; ) {

            [arrayLine1a insertObject:[arrayLine1 objectAtIndex:line1tagzahl2] atIndex:line1tagzahl2];

            line1tagzahl2=line1tagzahl2+1;
            a=a+1;
        }
```

function to create objects in array(this function is called very fast and frequently) :

```
for (float a=0; a<0.8; ) {
            UIImageView *line1 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Startpoint1.center.x-(w/2),Startpoint1.center.y-kurve1yf+a,w,h)];
            line1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unbenannt"];
            line1.tag=line1tagzahl;
            [self.view addSubview:line1];
            [arrayLine1 insertObject:line1 atIndex:line1tagzahl];
            line1tagzahl=line1tagzahl+1;
            a=a+0.1;
        }
```

now you should have more information

Comment: What exactly is your final goal here? As others comment below, simply copying an array to another can be done with "copy", but it might be you're not sharing some vital part of what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: How are you ending up with an index of 296 in this code?

Comment: maybe because array2 has many objects in it and probaly when the funktion above is initalized the objects in it are at 296

Comment: please have look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057135/copy-nsmutablearray-to-another) solution

Answer (score 0):

> and if you ask i have more than 10 objects in array2

Seems you haven't read the error message you posted. You have 296 objects in the array. But if you just want to copy the array, why don't you... er... copy it?

```
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [firstArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: because i only need certain obcetcs from the array these are uiimageviews and I want to make intersects with those in the other array and with the others not and the strange thing is that i have the capacity over 1000

Comment: @killerwakka Seems like you should be using a set instead an array.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any problem with using a default method `-addObjectsFromArray:` of NSMutableArray class?

```
- (void)serverGotResponse:(NSArray *)objects {
  [_myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent out of bounds exception, you should use `count` property:

```
while (i < array.count) {
   // do something ..
   i++;
}
```

if you are copying all the objects, you can just copy the entire array:
array2 = `[array1 copy]`

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to add the first 10 objects, but your exception was thrown on index 296, which is the first index that comes out of bounds.

For some reason, your `while` condition is not working properly, so I suggest you start looking there

I also suggest you use a `for`, it's actually more simple and straightforward than a potential infinite loop

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    [array1 insertObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:a] atIndex:a];
}
```